# System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer fails to deserialize the member

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

```
public class providerData
    {
        String rowId { get; set; }
    }

    public class providerPagedData
    {
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int totalPages { get; set; }
        public List<providerData> items { get; set; }
    }
    public class ProviderTest
    {
        String converted = "{\"total\":5,\"totalPages\":0,\"items\":[{\"rowId\":\"#10479\"}]}";
        public ProviderTest()
        {
            providerPagedData providers = new providerPagedData();
            try
            {
                providerPagedData p = JsonSerializer.Deserialize <providerPagedData>(converted,
                        new JsonSerializerOptions
                        {
                            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                            
                        }                    
                    );
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Result returns correct values for members "total" and totalPages, and correct number of "items", but "rowId" of the first element is always null.
Can't figure out what I am doing wrong and will appreciate any advise/help

Comment: Just a tip: Don't work with JSON strings like that. It becomes a pain to deal with over time. Just create anonymous objects and serialize those. You are guaranteed to have a solid data structure: `var obj = new { total = 5, totalPages = 0, items = new[] { new { rowId = "#10479" } } }`

Answer (score 2):

`rowId` is not being deserialzied because it is not `public`. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#public-and-non-public-fields):

> `System.Text.Json` only works with public properties. Custom
> converters can provide this functionality.

Changing to this should allow the `rowId` to deserialize properly:

```
public class providerData
{
    public String rowId { get; set; }
}
```